# CUDA Too many resources requested for launch

Tags: c, cuda

I have some problems running my code on a GTX 480 with Compute Capability 2.0

I always get following error if I launch the kernel with 1024 threads per Block:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchOutOfResources (error 7) due to "too many resources requested for launch" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef613]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/libcudart.so.6.5 (cudaLaunch + 0x17e) [0x3686e]
=========     Host Frame:./bin/myProgram [0x3a50]
=========     Host Frame:./bin/myProgram [0x388a]
=========     Host Frame:./bin/myProgram [0x38e3]
=========     Host Frame:./bin/myProgram [0x2a99]
=========     Host Frame:./bin/myProgram [0x1410]
=========     Host Frame:./bin/myProgram [0x1da0]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xed) [0x2176d]
=========     Host Frame:./bin/myProgram [0x1139]
=========
```

I run the program multiple time with different block and thread count:

```
5 Blocks, 512 Threads per Block => Works
5 Blocks, 1024 Threads per Block => Error
10 Blocks, 512 Threads per Block => Works
10 Blocks, 1024 Threads per Block => Error
15 Blocks, 512 Threads per Block => Works
15 Blocks, 1024 Threads per Block => Error
```

I checked the used registers, and it seems to be ok. "Function4" with 28 registers is the kernel which uses so much threads. All other kernerls uses only <<<1, 32>>> per call.

```
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z7function1Py
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z13function2PyS_i' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z13function2PyS_i
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 22 registers, 52 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6function3PyiS_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6function3PyiS_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 22 registers, 56 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z17function4PyiiS_Phji' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z17function4PyiiS_Phji
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 28 registers, 72 bytes cmem[0]
```

I run this program with my GTX 660 too with CC 3.0 and there it works with 1024 Threads per Block. I have no clue where the problem come from. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: It may be a registers per thread issue.  Try compiling the code with `-maxrregcount 28` (or `24`) and see if it affects the failing cases.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error.

Thanks to http://cuda-programming.blogspot.fr/2013/01/handling-cuda-error-messages.html, I understood the error. They say :

"Too Many Resources Requested for Launch - This error means that the number of registers available on the multiprocessor is being exceeded. Reduce the number of threads per block to solve the problem."

Basically I used to be able to have a given number of threads per block, (8x8x16=1024 for a 3D Kernel). But if you nest your kernel calls, you further reduce the number of available registers.

Comment: interestingly, I found with a particular kernel (quite large, with lots of nested calls) I could launch with 512 threads in debug, but when compiled for release, that failed, and it would only work with 256. A release build had heavier register usage it seems.