# CUDA - Crash on reading variable

Tags: c++, cuda

So, I'm trying to port [this raytracer](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html) to CUDA, and I'm running into some trouble when trying to adapt the code to test for collision with a list of hittable objects.

More specifically, I have the following code to test for collisions:

```
__device__ bool hittable_list_hit(const ray& r, double t_min, double t_max, hit_record& rec, uint8_t* data, int& offset) {
    hit_record temp_rec = { point3(0,0,0), point3(0,0,0), 0.0, false };
    bool hit_anything = false;
    auto closest_so_far = t_max;

    //printf("%f", temp_rec.t); <-- UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE MAKES CUDA CRASH

    uint8_t size = data[offset++];

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (top_level_hit(r, t_min, closest_so_far, temp_rec, data, offset)) {
            hit_anything = true;
            //closest_so_far = temp_rec.t;
            //rec = temp_rec;
        }
    }

    return hit_anything;
}
```

If I keep the highlighted line commented, the output of the program is a nice sky background (as in the raytracing tutorial). But if I uncomment it, the output is a black screen, and I suspect it might be a CUDA crash. **It seems like reading this variable makes CUDA crash for some reason.**

I'm relatively new to CUDA, so I have no clue why this might be happening. Does anybody have any idea on why reading a normal variable can cause this?

If it helps, this function is 4 levels deep after the kernel launch. Perhaps this nesting can cause problems?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerated-ray-tracing-cuda/

Comment: Oh, I didn't know somebody had made that already. Thanks a lot! However, I would like to give it a try at doing this project myself, so my original question still stands

Comment: compile the code with `-lineinfo` and use compute-sanitizer to find the line that causes the crash.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I managed to figure out what was happening! Thanks to [Abator Abetor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5206464/abator-abetor)'s answer, I took a look at what `compute-sanitizer` outputted, and I was getting a "Too Many Resources Requested for Launch" error.

Also thanks to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201172/cuda-too-many-resources-requested-for-launch), I saw that a potential solution was reducing the number of threads per block, and that worked for me! I also changed all doubles in my code to floats, just to be sure.

In short: whenever you are faced with a weird CUDA crash, `compute-sanitizer` is your friend :-)

Comment: You don't even need `compute-sanitizer` for this kind of issue, just use proper CUDA runtime error checking: [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)

Comment: Oh, I tried that one too, and it gave me the same "too many resources" error, but there was not even a black screen, so I thought this way of checking was causing some other problem with the code. Thanks for the tip!